# Java - How to pass a Generic parameter as Class<T> to a constructor

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a problem here that still cannot solve, the thing is I have this abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractBean<T> {
    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractBean(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I have another class that inherits this abstract:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BasicUserBean<T extends BasicUser> extends AbstractBean<T>  {
    private Class<T> user;    

    public BasicUserBean() {  
        super(user);  // Error: cannot reference user before supertype contructor has been called.
    }
}
```

My question is how can I make this to work?, I am trying to make the class **BasicUserBean** inheritable, so if I have class **PersonBean** which inherits **BasicUserBean** then I could set in the Generic the entity **Person** which also inherits the entity **BasicUser**. And it will end up being:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PersonBean extends BasicUserBean<Person>  {

    public PersonBean() {
        super(Person.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

I just want to inherit the basic functionality from BasicUserBean to all descendants, so I do not have to repeat the same code among all descendants. Thanks!.

Comment: So what is the problem with your last code snippet?

Comment: The compiler throws the error: "cannot reference user before supertype contructor has been called".

Comment: What's the problems with `super(Person.class);` snippet, I mean?

Comment: what is your `BasicUser` class...? any code snippet? also `Person` class might be helpful.

Comment: Do you want subclasses to take place of `Person.class`?

Comment: The error is on the first and second code block or just the first?

Comment: Alex, the problem is not the super(Person.Class), the problem is in the BasicUserBean class in the line "super(user)"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the constructor to `BasicUserBean` taking a `Class<T>`

```
public BasicUserBean(Class<T> entityClass) {
    super(entityClass);
}
```

Your no argument constructor won't work since the class you're extending requires a `T`. You **can't** have a `T` in your constructor without taking in a `T` as an argument; not without a *cast* anyway.

Comment: Then the no argument `BasicUserBean()` constructor and `user` member property can be safely removed also as they won't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks Johan, that solved the problem. Even thought, after this I received a compiler message saying "EJB class must have a public or protected no-args constructor", so I just added a "no-arg" constructor to both, the abstract class and the BasicUserBean class and it's working fine now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you cannot pass an instance field to a call to the super constructor. Notice that the field `user` is always `null` at the point you call `super` so what would be the point. You will need to pass the `user` into the constructor and pass that to the `super` or set `user` as a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If AbstractUserBean is your own class and you're allowed to change it, you can replace its constructor from

```
public AbstractBean(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}
```

to this one

```
public AbstractBean() {
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<T>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

So no parametrized constructors required at all.